# Python Pandas time difference from the start of every day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-difference

I've got the following data frame on pandas:

```
d = {'col_Date_Time': ['2020-08-01 00:00:00', 
                       '2020-08-01 00:10:00', 
                       '2020-08-01 00:15:00', 
                       '2020-08-01 00:19:00',
                       '2020-08-01 01:19:00',
                       '2020-08-02 00:00:00', 
                       '2020-08-02 00:15:00', 
                       '2020-08-02 00:35:00',
                       '2020-08-02 01:35:00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = pd.to_datetime(df.col_Date_Time)
```

I want to add another column that contains the number of minutes from the start of each day.

So, the result in this case woud be:

> ```
>        NAN 
>        10 
>        15 
>        19 
>        79
>        NAN 
>        15 
>        35
>        95
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_Date_Time': ['2020-08-01 00:00:00', 
                       '2020-08-01 00:10:00', 
                       '2020-08-01 00:15:00', 
                       '2020-08-01 00:19:00', 
                        '2020-08-01 01:23:00',
                       '2020-08-02 00:00:00', 
                       '2020-08-02 00:15:00', 
                       '2020-08-02 00:35:00',
                        '2020-08-02 06:31:00']})
df['col_Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.col_Date_Time)
df['start_day_time_stamp']=list(map(lambda x: x.date(),df['col_Date_Time'])) 
df['mins_from_day_start']=((pd.to_datetime(df['col_Date_Time'])-pd.to_datetime(df['start_day_time_stamp'])).dt.total_seconds())/60
df
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it restarts at the beginning of every hour not every day

Comment: Can you also edit the question  and do you need minutes from start of every hour in a time stamp ?

Comment: I need number of minutes since the start of every day

Comment: Hi @DarioFederici  I have updated the answer . Please check . it would give you total minutes from each day start. I have added some samples in sample DF to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
s = df.dt.minute.where(df.dt.date.duplicated())
Out[66]: 
0     NaN
1    10.0
2    15.0
3    19.0
4     NaN
5    15.0
6    35.0
Name: col_Date_Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry it restarts at the beginning of every hour not every day

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the column to days (**.dt.floor('d')**), subtract this to col_Date_Time, and save in another column:

```
df["DELTA"] = df.col_Date_Time - df.col_Date_Time.dt.floor('d')
```

If you want this like integer:

```
    df["DELTA2"] = df.DELTA.dt.seconds.div(60).astype(int) 
    col_Date_Time   DELTA   DELTA2
0   2020-08-01 00:00:00 00:00:00    0
1   2020-08-01 00:10:00 00:10:00    10
2   2020-08-01 00:15:00 00:15:00    15
3   2020-08-01 00:19:00 00:19:00    19
4   2020-08-01 01:19:00 01:19:00    79
5   2020-08-02 00:00:00 00:00:00    0
6   2020-08-02 00:15:00 00:15:00    15
7   2020-08-02 00:35:00 00:35:00    35
8   2020-08-02 01:35:00 01:35:00    95
```

Comment: Yours is the best solution but can you express the result in minutes